# Localstorage with redux tooklit for a shopping cart on an e-commerce application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I've built an e-commerce app and need the cart items to stay constant if a user refreshes the page. I have created a slice in this file where all of the actions are.  I was doing some reading on redux-tooklit-persist and it sounds like that might be my solution. I've included the reducer file as well as the file which contains the "AddToCart" function.

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialState = {
  isCartOpen: false,
  cart: [],
  items: []
}

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setItems: (state, action) => {
      state.items = action.payload
    },
    // Add item to cart
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      state.cart = [...state.cart, action.payload.item]
    },
    // Remove item from cart
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      state.cart = state.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id)
    },
    // Increase count in cart
    increaseCount: (state, action) => {
      state.cart = state.cart.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
          item.count++
        }
        return item
      })
    },
    // Decrease count in cart
    decreaseCount: (state, action) => {
      state.cart = state.cart.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id && item.count > 1) {
          item.count--
        }
        return item
      })
    },
    setIsCartOpen: (state) => {
      state.isCartOpen = !state.isCartOpen
    }
  }
})

//Export
export const {
  setItems,
  addToCart,
  removeFromCart,
  increaseCount,
  decreaseCount,
  setIsCartOpen
} = cartSlice.actions

export default cartSlice.reducer
```

Here is my Item.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { IconButton, Box, Typography, useTheme, Button } from "@mui/material"
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add"
import RemoveIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Remove"
import { shades } from "../theme"
import { addToCart } from "../state"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
    
const Item = ({ item, width }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false)
  const {
    palette: { neutral }
  } = useTheme()
    
  // Destructure from attributes
  const { category, price, name, image } = item.attributes
  const {
    data: {
      attributes: {
        formats: {
          medium: { url }
        }
      }
    }
  } = image
    
  return (
    <Box width={width}>
      <Box
        position="relative"
        onMouseOver={() => setIsHovered(true)}
        onMouseOut={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      >
        <img
          alt={item.name}
          width="300px"
          height="400px"
          src={`http://localhost:1337${url}`}
          onClick={() => navigate(`/item/${item.id}`)}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        />
        <Box
          display={isHovered ? "block" : "none"}
          position="absolute"
          bottom="10%"
          left="0"
          width="100%"
          padding="0 5%"
        >
          <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
            <Box
              display="flex"
              alignItems="center"
              backgroundColor={shades.neutral[100]}
              borderRadius="3px"
            >
              <IconButton onClick={() => setCount(Math.max(count - 1, 1))}>
                <RemoveIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography color={shades.primary[300]}>
                {count}
              </Typography>
              <IconButton onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                <AddIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                dispatch(addToCart({ item: { ...item, count } }))
              }}
              sx={{
                backgroundColor: shades.primary[300],
                color: "white"
              }}
            >
              Add to Cart
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    
      <Box mt="3px">
        <Typography variant="subtitle2" color={neutral.dark}>
          {category
            .replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1")
            .replace(/^./, (str) => str.toUpperCase())
          }
        </Typography>
        <Typography>{name}</Typography>
        <Typography fontWeight="bold">${price}</Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}
    
export default Item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`redux-persist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) is the standard for `react` Redux state persistence.

While you *could* individually initialize and persist state slices from & to localStorage like Mohammad's answer, this is ill-advised as the act of persisting to localStorage is a side-effect in what is considered to be a ***pure function***.

This would be better abstracted into a custom middleware. The RTK maintainers have made it fairly easy to create middleware listeners with [`createListenerMiddleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware). You can create a middleware listener that reacts to specific actions, or conditions, to persist the store to localStorage.

I'd suggest just going with `redux-persist`. If you are already familiar with `react` and `redux-toolkit` it's a pretty quick setup/integration.

Example:

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import cartReducer from '../path/to/cartSlice';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ...other reducers...
  cart: cartReducer,
});
 
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  ...any middlewares and other configuration properties...
});
const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

At this point I'll also export a wrapper component that renders the `react-redux` `Provider` component and `redux-persist`'s `PersistGate` component.

```
export const PersistedProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      {children}
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);
```

Now instead of wrapping the `App` component with the `Provider` component you can wrap with the `PersistedProvider` component instead and provide the Redux store to the app ***and*** persist the redux state.

```
import { PersistedProvider } from '../path/to/store';

...

<PersistedProvider>
  <App />
</PersistedProvider>
```

Answer (score 2):

My friend, you have to use localStorage to store your data inside the browser:

```
const initialState = {
isCartOpen: false,
cart: localStorage.get("cart") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.get("cart")) : [],
items: []
}

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
        state.cart = [...state.cart, action.payload.item];
        localStorage.set("cart", JSON.stringify(state.cart))
    },
  }
})
```

Here every time when you dispatch your `addToCart`, your data will save in redux and **localStorage** and when you refresh the page, your **redux** will fill with **localStorage**.
I changed just one of those reducers, you have to change all of them based on **localStorage** and your **redux**.
If you get stuck, tell me, and I will explain it to you.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, I changed get to getItem(), same thing with setItem(). This is working but I know the reducer way mentioned here is better - will try both